# Using SQL*Plus to connect to remote DB from local server, how do I export a backup to my local server?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux, sqlplus, expdp

I am trying to have my entire remote DB backup made to my local server.
Running the following command from my local server: `expdp \"user/user@ip as SYSDBA\" full=Y directory=/backup/backup/ dumpfile=backup.dmp logfile=backup.log`
I am met with the following error:

> ORA-39002 invalid operation
>
> ORA-39070 Unable to open log file
>
> ORA-39087 directory name /backup/backup/ is invalid

I know the directory path on my local server does exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datapump uses directory objects in the database, not direct file system paths. It can only export/import from directories visible on the database server itself. Your only possible option would be to share a directory from your local server to the database server and have Oracle write to the shared folder, but that doesn't always work either depending on the share type (plus it would be a pretty big security risk). Using datapump there is no way to export to a client system the way you are trying to do.